# How to find the indexes of all occerences of a character in a string?

Tags: python, string, list, indexing

I guess the heading is self-explanatory, still, I'll make myself more clear.

I've to find the indexes of every occurrence of a character in a string. For example,

```
word = "banana"
def indexes(x, word):
    #some code
    return (list of indexes of x character in the word)
```

output:

```
indexes('a', word)
>> [1, 3, 5]
```

How do I get this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
word = "banana"
def indexes(x, word):
    output = []
    for i,y in enumerate(word):
        if x == y:
            output.append(i)
    return output

output = indexes("a", word)
print(output)
```

Comment: Thank you very much to help me. Your code surely works. But I've to mark the other guy's solution green as he answered first. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension

- [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) - method adds a counter to an iterable and returns it in a form of enumerate object.

**Ex.**

```
word = "banana"
indexes = [ index for index,x in enumerate(word) if x in 'a' ]
print(indexes)
```

**O/P:**

```
[1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: `x == 'a'`  <--....

Comment: Thank you very much man. Really appreciate. It works!

Comment: @ParthikB. The behaviour of `in` and `==` operator in python, [see this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in).

Comment: @ParthikB. you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

i would do something like this

```
word = "banana"
def indexes(x, word):
  result = []
  for idx, letter in enumerate(word):
    if letter == x:
      result.append(idx)
  return result
```

and then

```
indexes('a', word)
[1, 3, 5]
```